# What will let me find keyboard input for Mac (like AutoHotKey's console for Windows)?

Tags: osx, mouse, keyboard-shortcuts

My use case: I have a mouse with rocker buttons. I want to remap these buttons to be something else (forward and backwards). I know the button is recognized since it seems to allow for "open link in new tab" functionality when in Chrome - I know the button is sending *some* signal.

Using the keyboard viewer does not show what the button does. This is what I thought I would try first.

On Windows, using AutoHotKey a built in function basically gives a dump of all the scan codes windows receives to a console output. This would let me know exactly what button OSX is registering the keypress as.

- What application for Mac will display scan codes (or keyboard/mouse input) in a fashion which will let me remap the input? It can be either a GUI application or a terminal app

Comment: I know you can via wxPython; if that is a solution that interests you I can draft up a quick script to do so (at least it works that way on Windows and it is cross platform so I would expect it to be able to do that on Mac)

Comment: @NickWilde I'm fine with whatever works, even "hacks" - it's rather mind blowing to me this is so complicated in the first place...

Comment: As for actually remapping the key:

Have you tried Automator? I'm not sure what Automator does since I haven't played with a Mac in awhile, but it's for automating things, and there may be way to bind it to a key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install [Karabiner](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/index.html.en).

Then use its *EventViewer* ([look up the doco](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/document.html.en#eventviewer)) to monitor the events your custom device fires.

Comment: Great! This works! It even has built in hooks for exactly what I want to do, after digging around in it for a while.